# Convert Domino Web Application to HTML

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

Is it possible to convert a .nsf Domino Web Application to HTML? I need the application making available offline without the use of a Domino server. To elaborate on this, we have an external company that host a domino application for us, a document management system. They are soon going to pull the plug on the server and have sent us a .nsf file. If we had a domino server it would be great, we could just place the file on the server. But the problem is that we don't. That is why I was hoping if there was a way to extract all the content so that it could run without a domino server, just as a bunch of HTML files, we don't need the functionality of the DMS, we just need to be able to view the content.

Thanks

Comment: Question is way too broad to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is an application with logic and actions built on Domino's programming framework, and not just a set of static pages, then the answer is no.  First of all, because HTML is just a markup language, not a programming language or framework.  And secondly, because the various attempts that have been made to build tools to migrate Domino applications to other frameworks have generally not been very successful.  GBS has tools to migrate traditional Domino applications to XPages, but that's probably not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If the site is static you could copy it using a web site copy tool like HTTrack:  http://www.httrack.com/

The tool crawls the entire site and generates HTML pages.

Comment: Thanks, I did try that, however the problem is that the page content is generated via JavaScript and HTTrack doesn't support JavaScript generated pages.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Notes client, create a local replica of the database. With that database open in Notes, click on Actions in the top-line menu, then Preview in Web Browser, and choose Internet Explorer. You may need to change the ACL to allow Anonymous to have Reader access. If the data needs to be secure, create a local copy instead so that you can modify the ACL without putting the production copy at risk.

You can download the Notes designer client [from IBM](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/ls/dominodesigner/?S_CMP=LSDL) with no restrictions as well as the [Notes and administrator clients](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/ls/lsndad/index.html) with a 90-day evaluation period.